# Datatable in angular1 not able show lengthMenu

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I have a silly problem here, which is eating my day. I am displaying a angular `datatable`. The `lengthMenu` is not working at all and everything seems fine to me. My code in the controller

```
   $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                .withDisplayLength(50)
                .withOption('order', [1, 'asc'])
                .withOption('bLengthChange', false)
                .withOption('searchable', [3, false])
                // .withOption('lengthMenu', [5, 100, 150, 200])
                .withPaginationType('full_numbers').withDisplayLength(5)
                .withOption('lengthMenu', [[5, 10, 15, 20, 25,-1],[5,10,15,20,25,"All"]])
                .withOption('notSortable', 2);
```

My view

```
<table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions"
                 class="table table-striped table-hover dataTables-example" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>User Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Roles</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="user in userList">
                            <td>{{ user.userId }} </td>
                            <td>{{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }}</td>
                            <td>{{ user.role | displayRoleNames}}</td>
                            <td><span class="flex-inline">
                                <!--<a href="" title="View">View</a>   |   -->
                                <a  ui-sref="admin.edituser({id:user.userId})" title="Edit">Edit</a>   |   
                                <a href="" title="Ghost">Ghost</a> | 
                                <a href="" ng-click="deleteUser(user.userId,$index)" title="Delete">Delete</a>
                            </span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: any error in console ?

Comment: No surprise, since you turn the lengthMenu **off** by              `.withOption('bLengthChange', false)` :)

Comment: @davidkonrad I have figured out that. Thanks ;-)